# Why does halving the frame rate with FFmpeg barely reduce file size?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have some stream rips at ~2k kbps I'd like to cut down.

```
ffmpeg -ss 4:00 -to 4:10 -i in.mp4 -an -vcodec libx265 -crf 26 -preset slow 26s.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 4:00 -to 4:10 -i in.mp4 -an -vcodec libx265 -crf 26 -preset slow -vf fps=30 26sr.mp4
```

The first is 60 fps and 839 KB. The second is 30 fps and 807 KB. Why such a small difference?

Comment: The primary reason is in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/49620592/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because in video codecs, the differences between frames are recorded, only rarely the full frames. In modern video codecs, *especially* x265, predictive techniques (mostly motion prediction) are used to not even store when elements of the scene move at the same speed as they moved before.

So, by removing frames, you made the frames that follow on each other more independent and thus containing more information, even if it's only half as many.

Especially: you're specifically asking the encoder to roughly achieve the same visual quality – CRF – and that means that if a frame is more different to other frames, it will be encoded with higher quantization, yielding to more bits. That's exactly the intent you expressed with your CRF setting! If you want a smaller file, reduce the CRF setting, or go for an average bit rate setting by running with

1. `-b:v {desired bitrate, e.g. 200k} -x265-params pass=1 -f null /dev/null` on the first pass, and
2. `-b:v {same as above} -x265-params pass=2 26s.mp4` on the second pass.

Another trick, especially in video material where movement might be sporadic (videos of video call participants! But probably even more so surveillance video, zoo webcams), is to *not* specify a frame rate at all – that simply not being very useful for a situation where for some parts not much changes in the scene, and in others, rapid visual differences occrue – but use adaptive frame rate. For x265 in ffmpeg, that's what `-vsync 2` does; of course, you need to remove `-vf fps=...` for that to work.

Comment: "it will be encoded with higher quantization" --> that should be lower. Remember, zero quantizer is lossless.

Comment: The greater motion potential is a minor factor, since there typically isn't that much more motion 33ms apart relative to 16ms (30 vs 60 fps) and the no. of frames to be encoded have been halved. The main reason is the quantizer calibration. See my answer link in the comment under the Q.

Comment: I'm pretty sure CRF takes into account frame duration when deciding how many bits to spend, because the human visual system won't have time to notice artifacting in a frame that's very different from others.  You can test this by feeding it the same sequence of frames but with a different FPS.  (e.g. a real use-case could be a slideshow of photos; that's where I noticed it with x264.)  Oh, that was the same use-case as the Q&A @Gyan linked, [When compressing a set of images with libx264, why does frame rate affect final output size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49620592).

Comment: exactly, the file size for not-hard-to-do-with-the-lower-fps video is dominated by CRF, not by fps. That's the intent!